# Adding a screenshot to a product image in Photoshop 21.2.2

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, interface-design, mask, screenshot

I've downloaded the iPhone 11, iPhone 11 Pro, and iPhone 11 Pro Max product images .psd from [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/#section-products) and opened them in photoshop to add my app screenshot to them.

However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to add the screenshot to the layer correctly. It only opens as a new tab and no option will allow me to add it to the other psd. The layer reads "".

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Copy-paste your screenshot into the PSD file you downloaded. This will create a new layer containing your artwork. This layer should be the top most layer in the `Layers` panel. If it's not, drag to move it to the top of the layer stack.
- Move the screenshot layer around, scale and position to overlay the gray screen shown by default in the PSD template you downloaded.
- Right click your screenshot layer and choose `Create Clipping Mask`.

[image]

Comment: Hi, do you mind providing me with a link to the iphone frames with clear background, i am not able to find them anywhere with good quality. Also if there is any 3d would much be appreciated